# Are maya referenes the same as namespaces?

Tags: maya

How do I deal with references in maya? I have several scripts that I need to update to handle file referenced objects.

Are they they same as namspace?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

References are pointers to other scenes and are used for creating scene hierchies (parent scene, child scene, grandchild scene). You use them as an aid in the level creation process so that each time an asset is updated (or created), the level designer doesn't have to manually load them and position them in the scene (a reference is a target and the scene being referenced is the source).

Namespaces on the other hand are a bit like prefixes. They are assigned to groups of assets, meshes, whatever and yea... they are really nothing but a naming container, and they allow you to have several items in the scene with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference a scene with the Use Namespaces option turned on, Maya creates a new namespace that contains the imported or referenced data.

A namespace is a grouping of objects under a given name. Each item in a namespace is identified by its own name along with the namespace it belongs to.

By default, the basename of the imported or referenced file is added to the beginning of the imported or referenced object names, separated by colons.

For example, if you are importing a scene named foo.ma that contains an object named ball, after it’s imported the ball is named foo:ball.

You can change the prefix by selecting Resolve all nodes with this string and entering a prefix.

You can create, name, parent, and remove namespaces using the namespace command.

Namespaces do not effect selection, the DAG, the Dependency Graph, or any other aspect of Maya.